# SQL Server query timeout when restarting it is ok

Tags: sql, timeout

SQL Server is running fine application is also running fine but after every 15-20 days it is giving query time out exception and then if I restarted my Server machine then every thing is okay. Can any body give any clue so I can solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share your code? Or share a simple app that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tiny leak somewhere.

- Maybe memory is being used and not released.
- Maybe a temporary file is growing slowly.
- Maybe threads are being spawned and not released.

Look in the event logs for anything that has a continuous growth.